# How do I convert a WKScriptMessage.body to a struct?

Tags: swift, wknavigationdelegate

I set up the `WKScriptMessageHandler` function `userContentController(WKUserContentController, didReceive: WKScriptMessage)` to handle JavaScript messages sent to the native app. I know ahead of time that the message body will always come back with the same fields. How do I convert the `WKScriptMessage.body`, which is declared as `Any` to a struct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about safe type casting to, for example, dictionary?

```
let body = WKScriptMessage.body
guard let dictionary = body as? [String: String] else { return }
```

Or as an option, you can send body as json string and serialise it using codable.

```
struct SomeStruct: Codable {
    let id: String
}

guard let bodyString = WKScriptMessage.body as? String,
      let bodyData = bodyString.data(using: .utf8) else { fatalError() }

let bodyStruct = try? JSONDecoder().decode(SomeStruct.self, from: bodyData)
```

Comment: that second approach with a struct saved me: probably the issue was that String value had escapes in it, so just conditional unwrapping as? String neven worked. Thanks!

Comment: The body is not a always string. It can be a nested json object, including arrays, other objects, numbers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your defined struct

```
struct EventType:Codable{
    let status: Int!
    let message: String!
}
```

WKScriptMessageHandler protocol method

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: message.body)
        let eventType = try JSONDecoder().decode(EventType.self, from: jsonData)
    } catch {
        print("fatalError")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI message.body is String object. You can convert the body in dictionary like this:

```
            if let bodyString = message.body as? String {
            let data = Data(bodyString.utf8)
            do {
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
                    guard let body = json["body"] as? [String: Any] else {
                        return
                    }
                    //use body object
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
```

Comment: No, it may or may not be String. It depends on the javascript code which sent the message.